# PDFBox change page sizes and save it again

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

I´m trying to remove the Header and Footer of a PDF page, it´s necessary to search at the page break for some words, but it´s impossible with the header and footer, so it´s necessary to crop it and then convert to text than it´s "possible" to search the words.

I´m doing it:

```
PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load("document.pdf");

PDPage page = (PDPage) pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);

PDRectangle rectangle = new PDRectangle();
rectangle.setUpperRightY(page.findCropBox().getUpperRightY() - 100);
rectangle.setLowerLeftY(page.findCropBox().getLowerLeftY());
rectangle.setUpperRightX(page.findCropBox().getUpperRightY());
rectangle.setLowerLeftX(page.findCropBox().getLowerLeftX());

page.setMediaBox(rectangle);

PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
document.addPage(page);
document.save("newDocument.pdf");
document.close();
```

But when I change it to HTML, it steal keeps the text that was hidden. Is there any way to save it withou the croped area and convert to html correctly?

Thanks.
Best regard´s.